# Get all code completion options on WebStorm

Tags: macos, webstorm

[This page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Auto-Completing_Code.html) suggests by pressing <kbd>Control + Space</kbd> I should get a complete list of code completion options.

If I type a letter I do see the code completion options for that letter, but <kbd>Control + Space</kbd> on a Mac toggles the keyboard language. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `Ctrl+space` bound to input switching in OSX preferences, you have to re-bind either the OS shortcut or the IDE one to avoid conflicts; for example, you can assign `Cmd+space` to **Main Menu | Code | Code Completion | Basic** action in **Preferences | Keymap** and use `Cmd+space` to trigger code completion